# Is there any plugin for QGIS to calibrate contrast and brightness of a raster layer?

Tags: qgis, raster, imagery

I frequently need to deal with the contrast and brightness of raster layers in QGIS and I miss the tools in ArcGIS for this task. Should there be a plugin already developed for QGIS? If there is, where can one find it?
Regards.

Comment: If the plugin/core tool is not available (and I don't remember such tool among the plugins in the standard repositories) then please evaluate the possibility of supporting its development.

Answer (score 1):

To my knowledge, there's no plugin as such (although one would be useful). But you can achieve the same effects albeit with a bit more effort, by changing the range of RGB values for that raster layer.

On the `Style` tab of the `Layer Properties` dialog, you'll see a radio button marked `Custom min / max values` select it, then play around with the numbers. With a normal colour raster, the range of each channel is (0, 255), but there's nothing stopping you actually setting values outside that range to get a certain effect. There is also a `Contrast enhancement` option that tells QGIS what to do when it encounters an out-of-range value; you may want `Clip to MinMax` but play around with it to see what effect it has. Pressing `Apply` updates the image reasonably quickly, so while not truly interactive, its certainly usable.

As Giovanni says, QGIS is rapidly becoming a mature and popular project, and your support is always welcome. [Funding](http://qgis.org/en/sponsorship.html) a feature-request is the best way of getting a plug-in to do what you want.